# VB Net Class launched from Windows Scheduler

Tags: vb.net, windows-task-scheduler

My application contains lots of forms which use buttons, gridviews etc. I'v made new form (buttons, labels, richtext for api response for testing etc.) which gets data from API, tested it and works. My idea is to make task schedule in Windows and run this sync every day at 8 AM. I'v made a class which got only code for getting data and saving it into database (save new or update). How to make this particular class make run inside project with 100+ forms using Windows scheduler?

Comment: Classes just sit there until an instance is created. Or a shared method is called. Maybe you want a service.

Answer (score 1):

Below will be one of the (if not only) way forward :

1. Make a separate console application with this class.
2. Generate the exe file
3. Use Task Scheduler to run it at a specified time